# Unit testing a class that uses NSURLSession in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, nsurlsession

I am looking for the most effective way to unit test a class that uses `NSURLSession` to retrieve data from a URL. I have seen older examples of classes that implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol. From reading the `NSURLSession` class reference documentation, to use the same approach my class would have to implement the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` protocol. This I believe will also require implementing the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` and `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocols, which together contain a number of methods that I don't need.

Is there a simpler way to accomplish the same objective?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use protocol-oriented programming and protocol extensions to test `NSURLSession`. Here's a summary of my blog post ["Testing NSURLSession with Swift, Part 1: Mocking Classes You Don't Own"](http://masilotti.com/testing-nsurlsession-input/).

First, create a protocol for `NSURLSessionDataTask` so you can substitute it with mocks under test.

```
typealias DataTaskResult = (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void

protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: DataTaskResult)
      -> NSURLSessionDataTask
}
```

Then extend the framework class so the compiler knows that the protocol and the class can be used interchangeably.

```
extension NSURLSession: URLSessionProtocol { }
```

Now you can create a mock session which captures the passed in parameters.

```
class MockURLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    private (set) var lastURL: NSURL?

    func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: DataTaskResult) 
      -> NSURLSessionDataTask
    {
        lastURL = url
        return NSURLSessionDataTask()
    }
}
```

Finally, test that your `HTTPClient` sends the correct URL to the session.

```
class HTTPClientTests: XCTestCase {
    var subject: HTTPClient!
    let session = MockURLSession()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        subject = HTTPClient(session: session)
    }

    func test_GET_RequestsTheURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://masilotti.com")!

        subject.get(url) { (_, _) -> Void in }

        XCTAssert(session.lastURL === url)
    }
}
```

Make sure `HTTPClient` exposes the `URLSessionProtocol` property via dependency injection. Here you can use a default parameter to grab the shared session when nothing is injected.

```
class HTTPClient {
    private let session: URLSessionProtocol

    init(session: URLSessionProtocol = NSURLSession.sharedSession()) {
        self.session = session
    }

    func get(url: NSURL, completion: HTTPResult) {
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (_, _, _) -> Void in }
    }
}
```

This can be easily extended to test more input, other methods, or even the output. Again, check out [my blog post](http://masilotti.com/testing-nsurlsession-input/) for a more detailed explanation and example.

Comment: The thing is, this is a stub, not a mock.

Comment: what HTTPClient here